# 503 error while deploying Google App Engine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-503

I am trying to deploy an application on Google App Engine. While using appcfg.py to update my application, it is showing the following error:

Precompilation starting.

Error 503: --- begin server output ---

Try Again (503)

An unexpected failure has occurred. Please try again.

--- end server output ---

Precompilation failed. Your app can still serve but may have reduced startup performance. You can retry the update later to retry the precompilation step.

I dont know how to solve this problem. Can anyone suggest me a method to solve this? Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is just temporary. [See here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-downtime-notify/browse_thread/thread/95c487775d6a748d?hl=en).